# python csv reader and creating syslog object

Tags: python, csv, syslog

A newbie looking into python...can someone show pointers who can we consume a csv in python and parase out some interesting key/value pairs from that and construct a syslog to be send to a remote syslog server

Appreciate!

Comment: This is **not** a do-my-work-for-me-because-i-want-to-sit-on-my-backside site. In other words, slavery ended in most of the world a few hundred years ago, and I (as well as most others in these environs) are not willing to revive it in 2014.

Comment: I apologise if i have hurt your sensibilities ..it was a request for pointers...thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

maybe pandas.read_csv or pandas.read_excel can meet all your needs
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Please show us concrete examples of the data that you have in your CSV files, the required output, and your effort to date.

For CSV parsing you can read about the python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module.

For sending log messages to syslog you can look at the [syslog](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html#module-syslog) module.